# WinHttp GET request over HTTPS & TLS1.2 failing

Tags: vba, https, tls1.2, windows-server-2016, winhttp

I'm observing an odd failure of an HTTP GET request sent using WinHTTP in a VBA MS Access application running on Windows Server 2016, but which works fine in Windows 10...

```
With New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    .Open "GET", "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,localizedFirstName,localizedLastName)", False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & auth_AccessToken
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send
End With
```

I've been round the houses of many different issues, involving SSL3, TLS1.2 etc etc, and am still suffering the same problem, which is execution hangs .Send before a timeout error pops up.

Looking at the requests going out via Fiddler, the above one to api.linkedin doesn't even seem to hit fiddler at all. However prior requests to alternate linkedin endpoints (www ones) do work, and do get picked up in fiddler.

I've tested my setup using https://howsmyssl.com/a/check and that is showing that my requests are going out as TLS1.2. And I've been able to send HTTPS requests to the [www.linkedin.com](http://www.linkedin.com) endpoints which have been fine.

Its almost as if something in Server 2016 is blocking these https:\\api.linkedin.com endpoints before they even leave VBA, and/or there is an issue in WinHttp.dll and the use of the authorization header (note, the bearer token I'm using is 100% correct, so I'm confident its not that - as I noted, the request doesn't even hit fiddler, let alone get a denied bounceback from linkedin).

I would be eternally thankful to anyone who is able to help me out or point me in the right direction.

Note: I've also tested using different XMLHTTP60 and ServerXMLHTTP60, to no avail.

Comment: If I add the line .setProxy 2, "127.0.0.1" I then don't get an error, but stauts 400 bad request comes back, but request still doesn't appear in Fiddler. :/

Comment: Also, I'm getting httperr.log entries like the following:

2020-09-09 16:26:41 91.239.125.170 50919 91.239.125.170 80 HTTP/1.1 CONNECT api.linkedin.com:443 - 400 - URL -